# Vagrant & Chef - Cookbook *** not found

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, vagrantfile

I am trying to set up a simple development VM using vagrant and Chef as a provisioner. I am able to install chef using shell provisioner but it seems to me that the folder with chef recipes does not get mounted to the VM. It keeps complaining that cookbook *** not found. Here is my vagrant file and output I am getting

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  # This strange method defines the name of the Vagrant Machine
  config.vm.define "SubscriptionAPI" do |foobar|
  end

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "chef/centos-6.5"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  # config.vm.box_url = "http://puppet-vagrant-boxes.puppetlabs.com/centos-65-x64-virtualbox-nocm.box"

  # Boot with a GUI so you can see the screen. (Default is headless)
  # config.vm.boot_mode = :gui

  # Assign this VM to a host-only network IP, allowing you to access it
  # via the IP. Host-only networks can talk to the host machine as well as
  # any other machines on the same network, but cannot be accessed (through this
  # network interface) by any external networks.
  config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.99.101"

  # Assign this VM to a bridged network, allowing you to connect directly to a
  # network using the host's network device. This makes the VM appear as another
  # physical device on your network.
  # config.vm.network :bridged

  # Forward a port from the guest to the host, which allows for outside
  # computers to access the VM, whereas host only networking does not.
  config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080
  config.vm.forward_port 443, 44343

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # an identifier, the second is the path on the guest to mount the
  # folder, and the third is the path on the host to the actual folder.
  # config.vm.share_folder "www", "/www", "../www"

  # Make sure the chef is intalled to the VM
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provisioning/utils/tools/install_chef.bash"

  # Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path, roles
  # path, and data_bags path (all relative to this Vagrantfile), and adding 
  # some recipes and/or roles.
  #
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.roles_path = "provisioning/chef/roles"
    chef.cookbooks_path = "provisioning/chef/cookbooks"
    chef.add_role "vagrant-test-box"

  #  chef.cookbooks_path = "provisioning/chef/cookbooks"
  #  chef.add_recipe "httpd"
  #  chef.roles_path = "chef/roles"
  #  chef.data_bags_path = "chef/databags"
  #  chef.add_role "devbox"
  #
  #   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
  #   chef.json = { :mysql_password => "foo" }
  end

  config.vm.host_name = "subscriptionapi"

end
```

The output

```
==> SubscriptionAPI: Thank you for installing Chef!
==> SubscriptionAPI: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> SubscriptionAPI: Running chef-solo...
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:04+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:04+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.0.3 ***
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:04+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 3442
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:08+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[vagrant-test-box]"] from CLI options
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:08+00:00] INFO: Run List is [role[vagrant-test-box]]
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:08+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [httpd]
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:08+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for subscriptionapi
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:08+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:08+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:08+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:08+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:08+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:09+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook httpd not found. If you're loading httpd from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
==> SubscriptionAPI: [2014-12-24T12:20:09+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

provisioning/chef/roles/vagrant-test-box.rb

```
# Name of the role should match the name of the file
name "vagrant-test-box"

# Run list function we mentioned earlier
run_list(
    "recipe[httpd]"
)
```

provisioning/chef/cookbooks/httpd/recipes/default.rb

```
package("httpd")
```

It's been forever I am trying to fix the issue by digging the Internet and checking different sorts of permissions over and over again - and still no luck

Comment: Can you ensure the cookbooks are uploaded to the box via a vagrant ssh and `ls /tmp/vagrant*/provisoning/` ? I'm not using chef-solo, but looks like vagrant did not copy the cookbooks. If it's the case you may have to use a shared folder (and according to vagrant doc, it sounds like a bug)

Comment: I have the following - /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/recipes (empty), /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/roles (with roles copied over), /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/dna.json (contains the runlist) and /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/solo.rb with some directories set up. cookbook_path ["/tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks"] - and it is empty

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It was vagrant-berkshelf plugin causing the issue. Uninstalling it made everything work flawlessly

Comment: You could either do that, or include those cookbooks in Berksfile.