# Provisioning vagrant box with chef_ solo

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo, vagrantfile

I'm having a problem with the chef-solo provisioner failing with the error 
**Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook apt not found.**

Any ideas on what could be going wrong here and how should I try to troubleshoot this?

- Host: Windows 7 64bit, Guest: Ubuntu 12.04
- Virtualbox 4.3.20
- ChefDK 0.4.0
- Vagrant 1.7.2
- Vagrant plugins:

  - vagrant-berkshelf (4.0.2)
  - vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)
  - vagrant-share   (1.1.3, system)

Vagrant output:

```
    PS C:\VagrantBoxes\mybox> vagrant reload --provision
    default: The Berkshelf shelf is at "C:/Users/dmit77/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150208-6588-1a3oox5-default"
==> default: Sharing cookbooks with VM
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.12
    default: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/VagrantBoxes/mybox
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef/7159cf65a6eea91634c03008165d96a8/cookbooks => C:/Users/dkrantsber/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150208-6588-1a3oox5-default
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> default: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:07+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.4.0 ***
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:08+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[apt]", "recipe[apache2]"] from JSON
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:08+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[apt], recipe[apache2]]
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:08+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [apt, apache2]
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:08+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for vagrant.vm
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:08+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:08+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:08+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:08+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:08+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2015-02-08T05:09:08+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook apt not found. If you're loading apache2 from another cookbook, make sure you confi
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Vagrant file:

```
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "opscode-ubuntu-12.04_chef-11.4.0"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://opscode-vm-bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/opscode_ubuntu-12.04_chef-11.4.0.box"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true


  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe :'apt'
    chef.add_recipe 'apache2'
    chef.json = {
      :apache => {
        :default_site_enabled => "true",
        :dir                  => "/etc/apache2",
        :log_dir              => "/var/log/apache2",
        :error_log            => "error.log"
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Folder structure:

```
[my_box]
[cookbooks]
    [apt]
    [apache2]
Vagrantfile
```

Comment: You can try to ssh your box (`vagrant ssh`) and check if in the folder `/tmp/vagrant-chef/7159cf65a6eea91634c03008165d96a8/cookbooks`  there are the cookbooks. Also check if the cookbooks have a metadata.rb file and it looks correct.

Comment: This folder (/tmp/vagrant-chef/a216041e14f8db851996624148ca222a/cookbooks) is empty on my vagrant box. 
What can possibly prevent cookbooks from being copied into it?


Also on my host machine the's no cookbooks/apt/metadata.rb file. Instead it's metadata.json. I have pulled this cookbook using librarian-chef. Could it be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I finally came across the solution. It turns out that **vagrant-berkshelf** plugin is the problem. Uninstalling it resolves the issue. 
[Vagrant & Chef - Cookbook *** not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687647/vagrant-chef-cookbook-not-found)