# Vagrant / Chef - Cookbook not found

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, provisioning

I'm trying to provision a vagrant VM with chef but I keep getting the following message:

"ERROR: cookbook sis not found. If you're loading sis from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata."

My current default.rb file is the following:

```
bash "apt update" do
code "apt-get update"
end

# manually install php 5.5....
execute "yum install -y --skip-broken php55w php55w-devel php55w-cli php55w-snmp php55w-soap php55w-xml php55w-xmlrpc php55w-process php55w-mysqlnd php55w-pecl-memcache php55w-opcache php55w-pdo php55w-imap php55w-mbstring"

bash "install mysql-server 5.1.69" do
user "root"
cwd "/tmp"
code <<-EOH
groupadd mysql
useradd -r -g mysql mysql
cd /usr/local
wget http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.1/mysql-5.1.69-linux-i686-glibc23.tar.gz
tar zxvf mysql-5.1.69-linux-i686-glibc23.tar.gz
rm mysql-5.1.69-linux-i686-glibc23.tar.gz
ln -s mysql-5.1.69-linux-i686-glibc23 mysql
cd mysql
chown -R mysql .
chgrp -R mysql .
scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
chown -R root .
chown -R mysql data
cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
EOH
not_if do
File.exists?("/etc/my.cnf")
end
end

bash "start mysql-server 5.1.69" do
user "root"
code <<-EOH
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server start
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -e 'GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root;'
EOH
end
```

And my metadata file is the following:

```
name             "Test Machine" 
maintainer       "Claudio"
maintainer_email "******"
license          "All rights reserved"
description      "Installs/Configures sis"
long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'README.md'))
version          "0.0.1"
```

My current Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
# All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
# options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
# please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

# Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
config.vm.box = "precise32"

# The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
# doesn't already exist on the user's system.
config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 512]
config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.100.10"
#config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"


# Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path, roles
# path, and data_bags path (all relative to this Vagrantfile), and adding 
# some recipes and/or roles.
#
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
 chef.cookbooks_path = "./cookbooks"
 chef.roles_path = "./roles"
 chef.data_bags_path = "./data_bags"

 #hef.add_recipe "sis"
 #chef.add_role "web"

  # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
  chef.json = { :mysql_password => "foo" }
  end

end
```

Any idea on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Execute and bash steps should be the exception in chef recipes.  The package resource handles yum for example.

Comment: Where does 'sis' actually appear in your code?   You only show in the cookbook description & that's not gonna throw an error.

Comment: I have the sis folder in cookbooks/sis. The sis folder holds the recipes folder.

Comment: so, this sis itself?  i.e. you pasted in **cookbooks/sis/recipes/default.rb**?  are you using berkshelf?

Comment: ok, so first my depends "sis" solves nada.  I assumed you were *using* sis, not that you were *on* sis.  Second, your whole **recipes/default.rb** is somewhat besides the point as well - **the problem is more likely in the wider way that you've configured Chef and Vagrant**.  What does your Vagrantfile look like?  What does your Berksfile look like (assuming you are using Berks).  In fact, run **chef --v** on your command line and paste the results in your post, it'll tell us what Chef you are using.

Comment: And try to paste in some of the wider context of your error message so we know what program/tool is throwing it.

Comment: Trying to figure this out, I was trying to use chef to have a machine with mysql 5.1 and php 5.5 to do some testing. But it seems that chef is too much for me at the moment. I'm having trouble grasping the basics of it. I'm not using Berksfile.

Comment: yeah, I hear you.  Chef is powerful, but it took me 3 months to start getting comfortable with it and they were not happy 3 months.  OK, not using Berksfile is not necessarily a problem - that's something that you use to re-use other people's cookbooks.  But you **do** want to post your Vagrantfile.  Just make sure you remove any confidential info from it, please.

Comment: I'll remove my comments about how to use Chef shortly.  It seems stupid to make recommendations if I can't solve the basic problem at hand.  But I suggest you take note of it or copy it.  Unfortunately, good Chef intros are hard to find, people immediately jump to complicated topics for cookbook *authors* rather than *end users* like you or me.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687647/vagrant-chef-cookbook-not-found.   Vagrant may still think bershelf is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` in metadata should show name of the cookbook. It does not really matter what the folder name is, where your cookbook is situated.

Your problem is that you have "Test Machine" cookbook in cookbooks, but include "sis" recipe in Vagrantfile. Either change name to "sis" in metadata.rb or change `chef.add_recipe "sis"` to `chef.add_recipe "Test Machine"` in Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 0):

Your metadata.rb state:

```
name             "Test Machine"
```

Your cookbook should reside in a folder named "Test Machine", not "sis". or your metadata.rb have to be updated.

Take some time on [learning chef](http://learn.chef.io) to get over the basics of cookbook writing.

You don't say which version of chef you're using so I can't give more advice.

Answer (score 0):

if your recipe located at `cookbooks/sis/recipes/default.rb` 
then use like:

```
chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
chef.add_recipe "sis::default"
```

if you have multiple file like `cookbooks/sis/recipes/file1.rb...file2.rb` then use like:

```
chef.add_recipe "sis::file1"
chef.add_recipe "sis::file2"
```

also keep correct cookbooks  path  you can give fullpath of cookbooks like:

```
chef.cookbooks_path = "/home/user/fullpath/cookbooks"
```

> cookbooks_path (string or array) - A list of paths to where cookbooks
>   are stored. By default this is "cookbooks", expecting a cookbooks
>   folder relative to the Vagrantfile location.